# Parse paragraphs (<p>) that are between paragraphs with certain classes (<p class"">). BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a web page with a bunch of text. The format of the page is as follows:

```
January

1

text text text

even more text

2

text text text

even more text
```

I want to parse this page to a list of dictionaries that will look like this:

```
[{'month': 'January', 'day': '1', 'text':'sample text for January 1st'},
 {'month': 'January', 'day': '2', 'text':'text for January 2nd'},
 {'month': 'January', 'day': '3', 'text':'January 3rd'},
  ...]
```

This is what the html view of this page is:

**index.html**

```html
<div id="january">
  <h2><span>January</span></h2>
  <p class="subtitle centerline">1</p>
  <p>sample text for January 1st</p>
  <p>even more sample text</p>

  <p class="subtitle centerline">2</p>
  <p>sample text for January 2nd</p>
  <p>different sample text</p>
  <p class="right"><em>John Smith</em></p>

  <p class="subtitle centerline">3</p>
  ...
</div>
```

I successfully wrote the first part of the parsing script where I can get the month and the day.

**scrape.py**

```py
data = []
day_dict = {}
months = ['january', 'february', ...]

for month in months:
    month_block = soup.find(id=month)
    month_name = month_block.find('h2').string

    days = []
    for i in month_block.find_all(class_="subtitle"):
      day = i.string.strip()

      day_dict['month'] = month_name 
      day_dict['day'] = day
      data.append(day_dict.copy())
```

This yields the following list of dictionaries:

```
[{'month': 'January', 'day': '1'},
 {'month': 'January', 'day': '2'},
 {'month': 'January', 'day': '3'},
  ...]
```

Since the

tag with the sample text is not `child` of the date I can specify which paragraphs to get.

**Question**

Is there a way to only get the text that is located between two tags with the same class?
For example (in pseudo-code):

```py
for i in month_block.find_all(class_="subtitle"):
      day = i.string.strip()
      text =  month_block.find_all("p").after(day).before(day + 1) # new line in pseudo code 

      day_dict['month'] = month_name 
      day_dict['day'] = day
      day_dict['text'] = text # new line 
      data.append(day_dict.copy())
```

Excuse me for the rough pseudo code. If you want more details or explanation, please let me know.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: To print text you are looking for only p tag which contains `sample text for January` or you want all the p tag value like `sample text for January 1st , even more sample text`?

Comment: I want all the <p> tags that are between the day values. So, all the tags that you mentioned, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import bs4

calendar = {}

text = """<div id="january">
  <h2><span>January</span></h2>
  <p class="subtitle centerline">1</p>
  <p>sample text for January 1st</p>
  <p>even more sample text</p>

  <p class="subtitle centerline">2</p>
  <p>sample text for January 2nd</p>
  <p>different sample text</p>
  <p class="right"><em>John Smith</em></p>

  <p class="subtitle centerline">3</p>
</div>"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

for month_div in soup.children:
    month = month_div.find('h2').string
    calendar[month] = {}

    for entry in month_div.find_all(class_="subtitle"):
        day = entry.string.strip()
        events = []

        s = entry
        while True:
            s = s.find_next_sibling()
            if s and "subtitle" not in s.attrs.get("class", []):
                events.append(s.string.strip())
            else:
                break

        calendar[month][day] = events

print(calendar)
```

Output:

```
{'January': {'1': ['sample text for January 1st', 'even more sample text'], '2': ['sample text for January 2nd', 'different sample text', 'John Smith'], '3': []}}
```

Comment: I modified the code a little to stay in the realm of list of dictionaries, but your solution of using `find_next_sibling()` is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend another solution, which is very suitable for extracting data from XML.

```
from simplified_scrapy.spider import SimplifiedDoc 
html='''
<div id="january">
  <h2><span>January</span></h2>
  <p class="subtitle centerline">1</p>
  <p>sample text for January 1st</p>
  <p>even more sample text</p>

  <p class="subtitle centerline">2</p>
  <p>sample text for January 2nd</p>
  <p>different sample text</p>
  <p class="right"><em>John Smith</em></p>

  <p class="subtitle centerline">3</p>
  ...
</div>
'''
data = []
months = ['january', 'february']
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html) # create doc
for month in months:
    month_block = doc.select('#'+month)
    if not month_block: continue
    month_name = month_block.h2.text
    for i in month_block.selects(".subtitle"):
        day_dict = {"month":month_name,"day":i.text,"text":i.next.text}
        data.append(day_dict)

print (data)
```

Result:

```
[{'month': 'January', 'day': '1', 'text': 'sample text for January 1st'}, {'month': 'January', 'day': '2', 'text': 'sample text for January 2nd'}, {'month': 'January', 'day': '3', 'text': None}]
```

Here are more examples:https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples/